# When Exporting Group Members from Active Directory, some Group Membership appears to be encrypted, while others are not. What is causing this?

Tags: active-directory, ldif

This is what I am seeing for some group's membership in the .LDIF export from AD

changetype: modify
add: member
member:: 
 Q049U0FMQURJTk8uQ0FSTUVMQS4wMjAyNTQwNDIyLE9VPU5vbkNOSUMsT1U9QWN0aXZlLE9VPWlTaG
 9yZSxPVT1Ib3N0ZWQgQXBwbGljYXRpb25zLERDPUNOSUNTRFBVU0VSUyxEQz1Mb2NhbA==

Comment: Did you sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

The string in your question is in Base64 (I have replaced certain parts of the string with (withheld) for anonymity):

CN=(Withheld).CARMELA.(Withheld),OU=NonCNIC,OU=Active,OU=iShore,OU=Hosted Applications,DC=(Withheld),DC=(Withheld)

Are you using ldifde? If so, I believe the default mode for exporting files is ANSI. If there are Unicode entries (maybe this one), they will be converted into base-64 format by default. If you want to export a file into Unicode format, try using the -u switch.

Be aware that if you want to import, and you have unicode entries, but your file is not in a proper unicode format, you may need to also specify the -u switch. **Be careful when importing. Measure twice, cut once.**